# Check if the lengths inside a nested list are identical

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and I want to calculate first the size of each sub-list and then to see whether all those sub-lists have size 2. Therefore,

```
my_list = [["obj1", "item1"], ["obj2", "item2", "item1"], ["obj3", "item3"], ["obj4", "item4"], ["obj5", "item5"]]
lengths = [len(x) for x in my_list]
```

The list `lengths` contains the size of each sub-list. How can I check whether all my sub-lists have size two or not? In my example it should fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all` with a generator expression.

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
>>> all(len(sub) == 2 for sub in my_list)
False
>>> 
>>> my_list[-1].append(6)
>>> all(len(sub) == 2 for sub in my_list)
True
```

Or if the length does not have to be two specificly:

```
>>> subs = iter(my_list)
>>> len_ = len(next(subs))
>>> all(len(sub) == len_ for sub in subs)
True
```

Comment: Is not that the first statement is enough?  That one: all(len(sub) == 2 for sub in my_list)

Comment: I want just to check if all the sub-lists have size 2 or not.

Comment: @JoseRamon yes, that's what the first code is doing.

Comment: What about that one  my_list[-1].append(6) I do not get it!

Comment: @JoseRamon This was just to demonstrate that the solution works in both cases. In the first example, the outcome is `False` because the last list has length 1. In the second example, the outcome is `True` because I appended another element to the last sublist.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the number of unique elements in a list by converting it to a `set`.  If the length of the set is 1, and the only element of the set is 2, then you know that every list had length 2.

```
my_list = [["obj1", "item1"], ["obj2", "item2", "item1"], ["obj3", "item3"], ["obj4", "item4"], ["obj5", "item5"]]
lengths = [len(x) for x in my_list]

print(set(lengths))
# {2, 3}

len(set(lengths)) == 1 and set(lengths).pop() == 2
# False
```

Comment: This certainly works, but keep in mind that this would call len a million times for a list of length 1000000 with the first two sublists already having a different length.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one line:

```
print(all(map(lambda x:len(x)==2, my_list)))
```

First I map an on-fly function that check if the length is two. Then I apply all that returns True if all values are True, else False.

In production code, you could use assert

```
assert all(map(lambda x:len(x)==2, my_list)), 'Not all have length 2'
```

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). Mapping `len` with `my_list` to find length of the `sub-list`.

```
my_list = [["obj1", "item1"], ["obj2", "item2", "item1"], ["obj3", "item3"], ["obj4", "item4"], ["obj5", "item5"]]
all(i == 2 for i in map(len, my_list))
```

Output:

```
False
```

If you want to check all the length is identical.

```
my_list = [["obj1", "item1"], ["obj2", "item2"], ["obj3", "item3"], ["obj4", "item4"], ["obj5", "item5"]]
len(set(list(map(len, my_list)))) <=1
```

Output:

```
True
```